# Connection process

Tags: configuration

I have a D7 site online on linux server.
I made a backup of it on my Win PC usine Xampp server.

I cannot connect (as user 1)  despite i have the correct password.

How to follow to connection process to check where the problem could arise ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Nicolas

Comment: Here's some relevant documentation: https://www.drupal.org/node/44164

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you can reset the password.  However if you are syncing with your production site frequently, this will be a pain.

I think the underlying problem is that you did not copy the password hash salt value to your local site.

This is the $drupal_hash_salt variable in your settings.php file.

It is used in combination with the password to generate the hash code used to validate your login.  So if the salt on Server A is different than Server B, the hash will be different for the same password.

Note that some hosting services might be setting the drupal hash salt for you in an external file.  Make sure to check there as well.